# Using JavaScript and cookies to create user authentication and a notes app

Tags: javascript, cookies, html-input

I'm trying to create a simple notepad app (basic CRUD) using just JavaScript and it has to have a login/signup function, I've managed to create code to get a cookie, if the cookie doesn't exist it sets one and then deletes one after an expiry date.

Here is my cookie code:

```
function getCookie(usersCookie){
    if (document.cookie.length > 0){
        begin = document.cookie.indexOf(usersCookie+"=")
        if (begin != -1){
            begin += usersCookie.length+1;
            end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", begin);
            if (end == -1) end = document.cookie.length;
        return unescape(document.cookie.substring(begin, end));
        }
    }
}
function setCookie(usersCookie, value, expiredays){
    var ExpireDate = new Date ();
    ExpireDate.setTime(ExpireDate.getTime() + (expiredays * 24 * 3600 * 1000));
    document.cookie = usersCookie + "=" + escape(value) + ((expiredays == null) ? "" : "; expires =" + ExpireDate.toGMTString());
}
function delCookie (usersCookie){
    if (getCookie(usersCookie)){
        document.cookie = usersCookie + "=" + "; expires=Thu, 14-Jan-15 00:00:01 GMT";
    }
}
```

What I need to know now is how I save arrays to the cookie to access later since I can use this for the rest of the app, I'm replacing the DB with Cookies, I'm aware this is the worst way to do something like this, this is purely a self learning exercise to get used to using cookies.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `JSON.stringify`

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4];
var output = JSON.stringify(arr)
```

outputs

```
"[1,2,3,4]"
```

save this value in cookie and while fetching back use JSON.parse

```
arr = JSON.parse( output );
```

Comment: So the JSON.stringify function adds to the cookie? if so it seems too easy :)

Comment: @Longshanks JSON.stringify will give you string representation of array or json, you will need to use your already written functions to add to cookie and fetch from cookie.